# Can Qt show OSX Finder Choose File Dialog (QFileDialog::getOpenFileName) from an OSX dylib?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa

I'm making a Qt/C++ dylib on OSX. How can I get it to call QFileDialog::getOpenFileName() when there is no widget context?

(Background: See, what I'm doing here is building a minimalist Objective C Cocoa application that will load my Qt/C++ dylib to do most of the work. This allows me to use the OSX native webkit (something not provided by Qt/C++ in 5.5). I prefer working in Qt/C++ than Objective C. So, that's why I'm interested.)

Comment: Isn't there any equivalent dialog directly in Cocoa? I don't think you can do it in a clean way without the Qt Widgets or Qt Qml context because you need the parent windows, for example when dealing with modality. If it helps you, you can do it without the Qt Widgets module when using Qt Quick (https://www.kullo.net/blog/advanced-filedialog-in-qml/)

Comment: You might be better off approaching it so that your application front end is driven by the Obj-C/Cocoa framework, including file loading, then use your Qt dylib for driving your application logic.

Comment: To expand as well, `QFileDialog` has static functions that call for native dialogs, rather than Qt widget based ones. I can't say for certain whether or not it would work in a dylib, but in practise I would avoid running UI from a linked library as it creates difficulty when debugging and managing threads.

Comment: All great advice guys. I'll drive it from Objective C. Thanks. The answer is no -- one needs to drive it from Objective C, and anyway it's better to drive the GUI elements from Objective C and only use the Qt/C++ for the heavy lifting part of my app like database stuff, etc., since I prefer Qt/C++ so much. Good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer according to Simon Warta and Nicholas Smith is no -- it requires a widget context in Qt to drive that dialog from Qt. Since there isn't one in this case, I would have to drive certain tasks, which require such a context, from Objective C instead. However, Nicholas Smith also says that it's a better programming strategy to drive the GUI from Objective C in such a case, and drive the rest from Qt/C++ for the heavy lifting tasks such as database stuff, etc.

Since I'm building a project that uses Webkit mostly for the GUI and may only need something minor outside that for GUI, such as open a Finder file dialog, it's actually not going to be that much Objective C. The rest I can drive from Qt/C++, since I prefer that more.